# Ant design Upload component only work on second try

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using Ant Design upload component, every thing work fine but only on second try. When my page first load, the upload button is rendering with a + icon. When I first select a file, I can see that `handleUpload()` is called because of the upload button changing icon. But no request is sent to the endpoint (according to the network tool in firefox and my api logs). The console.log in handleUpload is showing a response stuck at 0% completion.
If I try a second time (or more), it's working perfectly. Why don't this work on the first try ?

Here is my Upload component :

```
return <div id="main-image">
                {recipe.mainImage ? (
                    <img src={recipe.mainImage} alt="avatar" />
                ) : (
                    <Upload
                        listType="picture-card"
                        showUploadList={false}
                        withCredentials
                        action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/http/upload-file?path=images/"
                        accept="image/*"
                        beforeUpload={(file) => {return true}}
                        onChange={handleUpload}
                    >
                        {uploadButton}
                    </Upload>
                )}
                </div>
```

And my handleUpload function :

```
const handleUpload = (info) => {
    console.log(info);
    if (info.file.status === 'uploading') {
      setUploading(true);
      return;
    }
    if (info.file.status === 'done') {
        setUploading(false);
        setRecipe({
            ...recipe,
            mainImage: info.file.response.fileUrl
        })
        return;
    }
};
```

upload button :

```
const uploadButton = (
    <div>
        {uploading ? <LoadingOutlined /> : <PlusOutlined />}
        <div style={{marginTop: 8}}>Upload your image</div>
    </div>
);
```

EDIT :
On the first try, here is the info.file logged in the console by `handleUpload()` function :

```
lastModified: 1682889865932
lastModifiedDate: undefined
name: "Hotpot.png"
originFileObj: File { … }
percent: 0
size: 111193
status: "uploading"
type: "image/png"
uid: "rc-upload-1696332634018-7"
```

There is no response inside. In the info return by Upload component, there is also no event object. Instead I have a  object with a lot of empty objects containing function names.

Comment: What is your `info` response status in your first try? You can also debug `event` response inside `handleUpload` function, maybe this helps us find the problem. Take a look [here](https://ant.design/components/upload#onchange)

Comment: I updated my post with more info but there is no response at all on the first try.

Comment: Does your server receive any events in this first upload?

Comment: No, according to my api logs and to the firefox network tool no request is sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that the button that was supposed to fire the upload request had a normal icon and a "loading" icon. When the upload begins, the icon was changed which cause the button to be reloaded before the request was fired.